# HttpContext.Current NullReferenceException in Static Method

Tags: asp.net, session, static-methods, httpcontext, nullreferenceexception

I have a static class with several static methods. In these methods, I'm trying to access the current thread's context using `HttpContext.Current`. For example:

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

However, when I do that, I receive a `NullReferenceException`, the infamous "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the static methods?  Where are they being called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't clear from the original post that the `HttpContext` is actually what's missing.  The `HttpContext.User` property can also be null at certain stages of the lifecycle, which would give you the exact same exception.  All other issues aside, you need to step through the source and see which part of the expression is actually `null`.

When you write code that references static methods/properties like `HttpContext.Current`, you have to write them knowing that your code isn't guaranteed to be run when the methods/properties are actually available.  Normally you have something like this:

```
static string GetCurrentUserName()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context == null)
        return null;
    IPrincipal user = context.User;
    if (user == null)
        return null;
    return user.Identity.Name;
}
```

Although I suspect that this wouldn't really solve your problem here, it would just get rid of the exception.  The issue is more likely that you're calling this method at a time or place when the context is simply not available, such as on a background thread, static constructor or field initializer, or in the `Application_BeginRequest` method, or some similar place.

I might start by changing the static methods to instance methods of a class that depends on an `HttpContext` instance (i.e. taken in the constructor).  It's easy to fool yourself into thinking that methods like `GetCurrentUserName` are simple "utility" methods, but they're really not, and it is generally invalid to be invoking a method that references `HttpContext.Current` through the static property from any place where you don't already have an *instance* reference to the same `HttpContext` (i.e. from the `Page` class).  Odds are, if you start rewriting your classes like this:

```
public class UserResolver
{
    private HttpContext context;

    public UserResolver(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public string GetUserName()
    {
        return (context.User != null) ? context.User.Identity.Name : null;
    }
}
```

...then you will likely find out *very* quickly where the chain is being broken, which will be the point at which you need to reference `HttpContext.Current` because you can't get it from anywhere else.

In this specific case, obviously, you can solve the problem just by taking the stack trace of the `NullReferenceException` to find out where/when the chain begins, so you don't have to make the changes I've described above - I'm simply recommending a general approach that will help reduce these sorts of "missing singleton" errors in the future.

Comment: It's not great to do this, but this is what I ended up doing. I also decided to strip a lot of the stuff I'd store in the object out and place it into the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this a few times, especially with static methods in another library and not my main project.  I've resorted to passing the HttpContext to the static method as a param when nothing else seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the null exception being thrown? Have you debug and see what is null? Is the HttpContext.Current is null or the User?

Comment: It's difficult for me to debug this because it doesn't happen all the time. In fact, I'm having a difficult time trying to repro this on my dev box, in the test environment, or in the live environment.

It seems to be happening at random with end users. I check for the null values and that's where it's being thrown (inside of the static method).

Comment: I wonder if the forms authentication ticket is expiring thus making the User null.